# jQuery validate - adding a rule causes validation to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have code like below to perform some conditional validation on fields in my form.  The basic idea being that if something is entered in one field, then all the fields in this 'group' should be required.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('readingRequired', function (val, el) {
    //Readings validation - if a reading or a date is entered, then they should all be ntered.
    var $module = $(el).closest('tr');
    return $module.find('.readingRequired:filled').length == 3;
});

//This allows us to apply the above rule using a CSS class.
jQuery.validator.addClassRules('readingRequired', {
    'readingRequired': true
});

//This gets called on change of any of the textboxes within the group, passing in the
//parent tr and whether or not this is required.
function SetReadingValidation(parent) {

    var inputs = parent.find('input');    
    var required = false;

    if (parent.find('input:filled').length > 0) {
        required = true;
    }

    if (required) {
        inputs.addClass("readingRequired");
    }
    else {
        inputs.removeClass("readingRequired");
    }
}


//This is in the document.ready event:

$("input.reading").change(function () {
        SetReadingValidation($(this).closest("tr"));
    });
```

This works fine, and I've used pretty much the same code on other pages with success.  The slight problem here is that when i enter a value into the first textbox and tab out of it, the validation fires and an error message is displayed.  This doesn't happen on other pages with similar code, rather the validation waits until the form is first submitted.  Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.  You know how it goes, post a question and then find a solution yourself.  Not sure why this works exactly, but changing my binding from:

```
$("input.reading").change(function () {
        SetReadingValidation($(this).closest("tr"));
    });
```

to

```
$("input.reading").blur(function () {
        SetReadingValidation($(this).closest("tr"));
    });
```

Seems to have solved this issue.  Would still appreciate being enlightened as to why that might be...